# SQL Query, get count() to output null instead of 0

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query, which basically counts the how many orders a customer has done:

```
SELECT name, count(order_id)
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN  orders
ON customers.name == orders.customername
GROUP BY name;
```

Output is something like this:

```
-------------
|adam |    2|
|bob  |    0|
```

Here bob had no entries in the orders table. So I believe the left join creates a table where adam has his order columns filled but bob does not.

But I want 0 to instead be NULL. Like this:

```
-------------
|adam |    2|
|bob  | NULL|
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that works for a lot of engines, is using a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT name,
       CASE
         WHEN count(order_id) = 0 THEN
           NULL
         ELSE
           count(order_id)
       END
       FROM customers
            LEFT JOIN orders
                      ON customers.name = orders.customername
       GROUP BY name;
```

And don't use `==` for comparison. In SQL it's just `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [NULLIF](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#nullif).

```
SELECT name, NULLIF(count(order_id), 0)
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN  orders
ON customers.name = orders.customername
GROUP BY name;
```